# Bevel modifier issues?

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I've got a part of a model that has some issues, I think due to the combination of subsurf and bevel modifier. I thought there could be a face orientation issue, or duplicate vertices but seems not.

Essentially I just want this bit smooth, but it's pinching at an edge. Still getting to grips with this but appreciate the help

Stew[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the *Angle* up to 41.5 (this value will preserve the final N letter) so that it doesn't bevel these edges, bevel will sharp them and create the problem you highlight:

[image]

You'll also need to slide this edge a bit (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: ..and the 'H' has a couple of pairs of verts which can be merged to stop the problems on that letter. Not sure what's going on with the final 'N' though...

Comment: for the final N, at 43° il looses its bevel and gets round, so maybe he needs to use bevel weights instead?

Comment: Thanks John Eason, I spotted the H issue just after I uploaded — that was a little bit of a legacy from trying different things at the start. On the final N, I've actually used Moonboots' suggestion with the angle but separated it out as a separate object. That means I can keep the angle lower for the bulk of it. 

Not sure if that's the optimum way to do it, I'm going to have a look at Moonboots' bevel weight suggestion instead, need to watch a couple of videos!

Thank you both — appreciate the help. A lot of times I feel like I'm figuring out workarounds but not sure what's 'best'